# Accelerometer signal processing

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, noise, filter-design

I'm new signal processing (this is my first pratical application), so I ask sorry if my question is simple.

My challenge is to see the displacement of accelerometer when I have vibration too. I do not know the vibration completely. The accelerometer will be attached to hoop of started vehicle.

I know that my "displacement have very low frequency" (maybe this statement is not adequate) in relationship vibration. The movement will be do moving accelerometer with hand. The vibration is coming of the vehicle engine.
 
I will use adxl362, it can work up to 400 Hz and can be programmed with low pass filter of 1/2 or 1/4 of output data rate.

I would like help with steps that I should follow to discriminate if  am vibrating or moving.

PS: 1 - I no need precision. 
      2 - After earch detect, the vibration and movement will be stopped.

Tnx very much for any help!

Comment: d is the double integral(f) of g(f) or (t)

Comment: The problem is integration of the vibration, some times I have false positive of displacement.

Comment: d vs f is easily graphed, simulated or electronically generated or computed from any g level. WHat are you doing?  LPF is not a good integrator unless on the slope of the filter

Comment: I m aquire acceleration, filter with low pass filter of cutoff frequency of 2 Hz and integrate 2 x. The problem is, when a have a vibration and do displacement 2 seconds after vribration start, the offset generated in matematical process is higher than the real displacement.

Comment: define f minimum in vibration. Does it include DC

Comment: Can you explain better, plx?

Comment: You have not defined your error values nor lowest frequency.  Perhaps you can give more details or use a real integrator